# How to simplify the keycloak rest API servie

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak, netflix-zuul

As of now I have completed the keycloak configurations and setup. Authorization also done . But I'm using using different rest services of keycloak (token_endpoint , Introspection_Endpoint ...). Is there any special keyclaok rest API or any other simple way to do authorization?

//GetEntitlement.java

```
public List<String> getEntitlement(){

  //Step -1
  //get access token from token_endpoint rest service     


 //"token_endpoint":"http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/MyRealm/protocol/openid-connect/token",

  //step -2
  //get RPT by Using Authorization:Bearer {AccessToken} header -->from token_endpoint rest service

 //"token_endpoint":"http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/MyRealm/protocol/openid-connect/token"

  //step -3
  //get the Permissions and resources by introspecting
  //Introspecting Rpt by passing RPT to introspection_endpoint

 //"introspection_endpoint":"http://localhost:8080/auth/realms/MyRealm/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect"


  //step -4
  //return the Permissions and resources

}
```

Answer (score 0):

USE proper JAR and Version.You need to paste your code you have done.So that we can verify and tell you proper answer or else you can find on keycloak documentation

Comment: Previous code is workig fine. but Number  of  Api calls make my application slow . So I need single Rest Api to complete the authorization.I hope the previous code is not required here. Thank You for the suggestion.